# Queuing a Spring Boot post request

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm using spring boot(2.2.2) to access and edit some excel sheets by triggering a bot, along with providing an API to view the data and am having trouble finding info on queuing tasks.

The bot I have to hit is legacy code I can't touch, triggered via a batch file, reads an excel sheet and does tasks based on the contents of the sheet. I have a post request that updates the sheet, but the problem is I need enough time between sent jobs so the bot can read the excel sheet specific to each job. The bot only reads one sheet saved in a specific place.

When 2 jobs are sent at similar times I get something like this

```
2020-01-14 13:38:11.808  INFO 9236 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] BOT status                               : Job Started
2020-01-14 13:38:13.464  INFO 9236 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] BOT status                               : Job Started
2020-01-14 13:38:16.830  INFO 9236 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] BOT status                               : Job sent to BOT
2020-01-14 13:38:18.216  INFO 9236 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] BOT status                               : Job sent to BOT
```

Where the jobs overlap and I can't be sure the bot got a chance to read the right version of each job.

How can I get the post requests to queue the jobs and wait until one job is complete before the next one is processed?

Comment: Share your post request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Spring boot @EnableAsync and @EnableRetry together for queuing purpose. Once you receive the request start processing the request in a separate thread using @Async annotation. In the Async method check if you re already processing a request then throw a custom exception. Using the Custom exception you can use Spring Boot @Retryable annotation to retry the failed execution after some time. You can use some database to store the status of Job processing.

Please check https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry for @EnableRetry
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async for @EnableAsync related configurations.

Comment: Thank you, put me on the right path. I did use the @enableasync decorator but used ```
 @Bean
   public Executor taskExecutor() {
     ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
     executor.setCorePoolSize(1);
     executor.setMaxPoolSize(1);
     executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
     executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Bot Process-");
     executor.initialize();
     return executor;
   }
```
and used that to limit it to one with a queue of 500 and stuck @async ontop of the method I wanted to limit.